# Where to use “avoir” and “être” in a description?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

I was doing one exercise. It confused me as I do not know the usage of “*avoir*” and “*être*” verbs in French.

> J'ai un nouveau copain. Il **est** assez grand. Il **a** un visage rond. Il **a** les cheveux clairs. Il **a** les yeux sombres. Il **est** toujours stressé mais il **a** un grand sourire généreux et il **est** sympathique.

Why have we used *a* and *est*?

Is this correct:

> Il est les cheveux clairs.

Today I did this exercise. Please explain how to make sure where to use the correct form of verb.

Even if I go by following logic,

- (*Avoir* – *a*) To have – to possess, own, hold
- (*Être* – *est*) To be – status or characteristics of something or of a person.

Still, I didn't get this: “*il **a** un grand sourire généreux*”. Is big smile a possession not a characteristic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the sentence

> **Il est les cheveux clairs.**

is wrong, you should use *avoir* :

> **Il *a* les cheveux clairs.**

But I admit I fail to see where an english speaker could not grasp the difference between *être* and *avoir* while understanding the one between *to have* and *to be*.

Comment: S'il _a_ les cheveux clairs, c'est donc qu'il _est_ blond?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is *not* an english speaker. :)

Comment: *blond* peut en effet qualifier aussi bien le cheveu que son *hôte*, d'où l'apparent paradoxe.

Comment: @Otiel ...but he could at least write a short english text here to ask his question... without knowing about *to be* or *to have* ? Are you nitpicking here ?

Comment: I'm not nitpicking, just raising a possibility. He could have written his question without really knowing about be/have subtilities.

Answer (score 6):

In these cases, where the matter is to describe something (or someone), you can chose between *être* and *avoir* by the same mean as in English

***Être* assigns properties and *avoir* assigns possession.** and there is an easy way to know which one you want:

**Properties are expressed by adjectives and possessions by nouns.**

E.g.

- To assign “*un grand sourire*” to *il*, you have to use *avoir* since *sourire* is a noun, thus

  > *Il **a** un grand sourire*
- To assign “*assez grand*” to *il*, you have to use *être* since *grand* is an adjective, thus

  > *Il **est** assez grand*

Note that this is only a rule of thumb and by no mean a proper formal set of rules. If you want that, you have to realise that your question is actually confusing two different things

- A [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29), that is, a way to assign relationships, membership, properties or positions to objects, expressed in French as in English and all Indo-European languages¹ *via* a so-called copular verb: *to be*, *être*. In programming, one would call this a IS_A
- A [possession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28linguistics%29) relationships, expressed in French as in English *via* a possessive verb: *to have*, *avoir*. In programming, one would call this an HAS_A.

So why “*Il a un grand sourire*”? Because body parts are considered to be possession, as are psychic features “*Elle a un esprit vif*” and lived years “*J'ai dix ans*”². I don't think³ it could be further rationalised without falling into the realm of speculative psychology (an individual has ownership of himself, blablabla) ; I would rather say that it is arbitrary.

By the way, “*Il est un grand sourire*” is grammatically and semantically correct, but means “he is nothing but a big smile”, *est* denoting here an equivalence.

---

¹ Yes, knowledgeable person, it has not the same importance and precise function in *all* IE languages.
² Je sais que c'est pas vrai.
³ But I would love to read serious linguistics rationalisations if someone has some.

Comment: So why: j'_ai_ dix ans ?

Comment: Tu **es** modérateur ;-)

Comment: Well, *dix an* is a noun phrase. And *modérateur* is a denominal adjective.

Comment: Or, in a different interpretation, nouns denoting functions can be used as adjectives.

Comment: @Evpok, _Tu es un modérateur du site_, à moins que tu commences à dire que « un modérateur du site » est un adjectif, je ne te comprends pas. (_Je suis un contradicteur têtu._)

Comment: Ça c'est une autre phrase. Le sens est Evpok ∈ {Modérateurs du site}, il ne s'agit pas de donner une propriété, comme dans « Evpok est modérateur » (ie « Evpok modère ») ou un attribut (« Evpok a un cerveau ») mais d'énoncer une appartenance.

Comment: D'accord avec Evpok : l'attribution et l'appartenance (voire également *l'identité*) sont des relations différentes, et la confusion vient du fait que le verbe *être* peut aussi bien exprimer l'une ou l'autre.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Si mes souvenirs sont bons, avec le concept de *copule* on considère juste que l'identité c'est l'appartenance à un singleton.

Comment: _Elle est un esprit vif_ me gène si peu que je me demande s'il n'y a pas des contextes où ce ne serait pas la formulation la plus naturelle.  Quant à [_il est un grand sourire_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheshire_Cat)...